# tikz node graph

Tags: graphics

i have a big graph

```
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} [
  line/.style = {draw, thick, -latex},
  dot/.style = {draw, fill=black},
%      scale=0.2
  ]
         \coordinate (0) at (0cm, 0cm);

         \coordinate (1) at (-20cm, 9cm);
         \coordinate (9) at (20cm, 9cm);
  \coordinate (2) at (-40cm, 30cm);
  \coordinate (8) at (40cm, 30cm);
  \coordinate (3) at (-40cm, 50cm);
  \coordinate (7) at (40cm, 50cm);
        \coordinate (4) at (-30cm, 70cm);
        \coordinate (6) at (30cm, 70cm);
        \coordinate (5) at (0cm, 85cm);
        \coordinate (10) at (0cm, 5cm);
         \coordinate (11) at (-15cm, 15cm);
         \coordinate (16) at (15cm, 15cm);
  \coordinate (12) at (-10cm, 22cm);
              \coordinate (15) at (10cm, 22cm);
  \coordinate (13) at (-25cm, 26cm);
        \coordinate (14) at (25cm, 26cm);
  \coordinate (22) at (-30cm, 57cm);
  \coordinate (18) at (30cm, 57cm);
        \coordinate (19) at (0cm, 43cm);
        \coordinate (20) at (0cm, 55cm);
       \coordinate (21) at (-20cm, 45cm);
        \coordinate (17) at (20cm, 45cm);
         \coordinate (23) at (-12cm, 40cm);
  \coordinate (24) at (12cm, 40cm);
  \coordinate (25) at (8cm, 51cm);
        \coordinate (26) at (-30cm, 34cm);
        \coordinate (27) at (30cm, 34cm);

  \draw (0) -- (1);
  \draw (0) -- (9);
  \draw (0) -- (10);
  \draw (0) -- (16);
  \draw (0) -- (11);

  \draw (1) -- (10);
  \draw (1) -- (2);
  \draw (1) -- (11);


  \draw (2) -- (4);
  \draw (2) -- (3);
  \draw (2) -- (22);


  \draw (3) -- (4);
  \draw (3) -- (22);


  \draw (4) -- (5);
  \draw (4) -- (6);
 \draw (4) -- (20);
  \draw (4) -- (22);


  \draw (5) -- (6);
  \draw (5) -- (20);


  \draw (6) -- (20);
    \draw (6) -- (7);
  \draw (6) -- (18);
   \draw (6) -- (8);

    \draw (7) -- (18);
  \draw (7) -- (8);

        \draw (9) -- (8);

        \draw (9) -- (16);
        \draw (9) -- (10);

\draw (16) -- (15);


  \draw (10) -- (11);
    \draw (10) -- (16);
  \draw (11) -- (12);
   \draw (12) -- (13);

  \draw (12) -- (27);
  \draw (12) -- (23);
   \draw (13) -- (27);
  \draw (13) -- (23);


  \draw (14) -- (26);
  \draw (14) -- (24);
   \draw (14) -- (15);
  \draw (15) -- (26);
  \draw (15) -- (24);

   \draw (17) -- (18);
  \draw (17) -- (25);
  \draw (17) -- (27);

  \draw (18) -- (25);
  \draw (18) -- (27);

   \draw (19) -- (20);
  \draw (19) -- (24);
  \draw (19) -- (23);
  \draw (21) -- (25);
  \draw (21) -- (26);

        \draw (22) -- (25);
  \draw (22) -- (26);

  \draw (21) -- (22);
        \draw (27) -- (23);
  \draw (24) -- (26);

  \draw (26) -- (25);
  \draw (27) -- (25);

  \draw (27) -- (13);
  \draw (27) -- (12);


  \draw (9) -- (8);
  \draw (3) -- (2);

  \draw (24) -- (26);
  \draw (27) -- (23);

   \draw (19) -- (20);
  \draw (20) -- (4);
   \draw (20) -- (6);
  \draw (20) -- (5);

        \draw (4) -- (6);

         \draw (25) -- (18);
  \draw (25) -- (17);
   \draw (25) -- (22);
  \draw (25) -- (21);

        \fill [dot] (0) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (1) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (2) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (3) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (4) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (5) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (6) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (7) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (8) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (9) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (10) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (11) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (12) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (13) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (14) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (15) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (16) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (17) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (18) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (19) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (20) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (21) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (22) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (23) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (24) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (25) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (26) circle (4.0mm);
        \fill [dot] (27) circle (4.0mm);
 \node (a) at (0cm, 0cm) {$u_1$};
 \node (b) at (0cm, 10cm) {$u_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}
```

And Im trying to use \node to node a coordinate but I have a mistake. I should be wrong somewhere. Can you help me with this? Can you also help me to draw any line in this graph into blue color? Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you converted your code snippet into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduced the problem. 

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.  As far as blue line, just add the `[draw=blue]` option to any `\draw`.

Comment: Which is the size of your picture?

Comment: The nodes are there, they're just very tiny, because your graph is huge, and you've resized it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about changing the color of one of the lines.  Here's a somewhat stream-lined approach:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: open
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\myunit{*4pt}
\makeatletter
\def\mycolor{}
\def\myextractinfo{\@ifnextchar*{\ae@extract@star}{\ae@extract}}
\def\ae@extract@star*#1;{%%
  \def\mycolor{blue}%%
  \def\mycoor{#1}}
\def\ae@extract#1;{%%
  \def\mycoor{#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
  line/.style = {draw, thick, -latex},
  dot/.style = {draw, fill=black},
%      scale=0.2
  ]


  \coordinate (0)  at (0cm, 0cm);
  \coordinate (1)  at (-20cm, 9cm);
  \coordinate (2)  at (-40cm, 30cm);
  \coordinate (3)  at (-40cm, 50cm);
  \coordinate (4)  at (-30cm, 70cm);
  \coordinate (5)  at (0cm, 85cm);
  \coordinate (6)  at (30cm, 70cm);
  \coordinate (7)  at (40cm, 50cm);
  \coordinate (8)  at (40cm, 30cm);
  \coordinate (9)  at (20cm, 9cm);
  \coordinate (10) at (0cm, 5cm);
  \coordinate (11) at (-15cm, 15cm);
  \coordinate (12) at (-10cm, 22cm);
  \coordinate (13) at (-25cm, 26cm);
  \coordinate (14) at (25cm, 26cm);
  \coordinate (15) at (10cm, 22cm);
  \coordinate (16) at (15cm, 15cm);
  \coordinate (17) at (20cm, 45cm);
  \coordinate (18) at (30cm, 57cm);
  \coordinate (19) at (0cm, 43cm);
  \coordinate (20) at (0cm, 55cm);
  \coordinate (21) at (-20cm, 45cm);
  \coordinate (22) at (-30cm, 57cm);
  \coordinate (23) at (-12cm, 40cm);
  \coordinate (24) at (12cm, 40cm);
  \coordinate (25) at (8cm, 51cm);
  \coordinate (26) at (-30cm, 34cm);
  \coordinate (27) at (30cm, 34cm);
  \foreach \myc/\myd in 
           {0/{1,10,11,16,9},
            1/{10,11,2},
            2/{22,3,4},
            3/{22,4},
            4/{20,22,5,6},
            5/{20,6},
            6/{18,*20,7,8},
            7/{8,18},
            8/{9},
            9/{10,16},
            10/{11,16},
            11/{12},
            12/{13,23,27},
            13/{23,27},
            14/{15,24,26},
            15/{16,24,26},
            17/{18,25,27},
            18/{25,27},
            19/{20,23,24},
            21/{22,25,26},
            22/{25,26},
            23/{27},
            24/{26},
            25/{26,27}%%
           }
    {
      \fill[dot] (\myc) circle (4.0mm);
      \foreach \myo in \myd
      {
       \expandafter\myextractinfo\myo;
       \draw[\mycolor] (\myc) -- (\mycoor);
      }
    }

 \node (a) at (0cm, 0cm) {$u_1$};
 \node (b) at (0cm, 10cm) {$u_2$};

 \draw[orange] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your nodes are there, but because of the scale (by setting coordinates in cm) the text is dwarfed by everything else.

In the above code, I allow you to prefix a coordinate with a `*` which is then parsed to set the color of that particular line `blue`.  This is a rather crude approach.

You could do something more sophisticated alone these lines:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: open
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\myunit{*4pt}
\makeatletter
\def\myparam{}
\def\myextractinfo{\@ifnextchar[%]
  {\ae@extract@star}{\ae@extract}}
\def\ae@extract@star[#1]#2;{%%
  \def\myparam{[#1]}%%
  \def\mycoor{#2}}
\def\ae@extract#1;{%%
  \def\mycoor{#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
  line/.style = {draw, thick, -latex},
  dot/.style = {draw, fill=black},
%      scale=0.2
  ]


  \coordinate (0)  at (0\myunit, 0\myunit);
  \coordinate (1)  at (-20\myunit, 9\myunit);
  \coordinate (2)  at (-40\myunit, 30\myunit);
  \coordinate (3)  at (-40\myunit, 50\myunit);
  \coordinate (4)  at (-30\myunit, 70\myunit);
  \coordinate (5)  at (0\myunit, 85\myunit);
  \coordinate (6)  at (30\myunit, 70\myunit);
  \coordinate (7)  at (40\myunit, 50\myunit);
  \coordinate (8)  at (40\myunit, 30\myunit);
  \coordinate (9)  at (20\myunit, 9\myunit);
  \coordinate (10) at (0\myunit, 5\myunit);
  \coordinate (11) at (-15\myunit, 15\myunit);
  \coordinate (12) at (-10\myunit, 22\myunit);
  \coordinate (13) at (-25\myunit, 26\myunit);
  \coordinate (14) at (25\myunit, 26\myunit);
  \coordinate (15) at (10\myunit, 22\myunit);
  \coordinate (16) at (15\myunit, 15\myunit);
  \coordinate (17) at (20\myunit, 45\myunit);
  \coordinate (18) at (30\myunit, 57\myunit);
  \coordinate (19) at (0\myunit, 43\myunit);
  \coordinate (20) at (0\myunit, 55\myunit);
  \coordinate (21) at (-20\myunit, 45\myunit);
  \coordinate (22) at (-30\myunit, 57\myunit);
  \coordinate (23) at (-12\myunit, 40\myunit);
  \coordinate (24) at (12\myunit, 40\myunit);
  \coordinate (25) at (8\myunit, 51\myunit);
  \coordinate (26) at (-30\myunit, 34\myunit);
  \coordinate (27) at (30\myunit, 34\myunit);
  \foreach \myc/\myd in 
           {0/{1,10,11,16,9},
            1/{10,11,2},
            2/{22,3,4},
            3/{22,4},
            4/{20,22,5,6},
            5/{20,6},
            6/{18,[{blue,dashed}]20,7,8},
            7/{8,18},
            8/{9},
            9/{10,16},
            10/{11,16},
            11/{12},
            12/{13,23,27},
            13/{23,27},
            14/{15,24,26},
            15/{16,24,26},
            17/{18,25,27},
            18/{25,27},
            19/{20,23,24},
            21/{22,25,26},
            22/{25,26},
            23/{27},
            24/{26},
            25/{26,27}%%
           }
    {
      \fill[dot] (\myc) circle (4.0pt);
      \foreach \myo in \myd
      {
       \expandafter\myextractinfo\myo;
       \expandafter\draw\myparam (\myc) -- (\mycoor);
      }
    }

 \node (a) at (0\myunit, 0\myunit) {$u_1$};
 \node (b) at (0\myunit, 10\myunit) {$u_2$};

 \draw[orange] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This time I allow you to prefix the second coordinate with a `[....]` block.   However, if this block contains comma, its content needs to be further bracketed to avoid being misinterpreted by `\foreach`.

Comment: I suggest changing all `cm` to `mm`, that makes that graph a more reasonable size.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I was thinking of doing that, but I wasn't sure why the OP originally chose `cm`.